# SQL Server Inner Join with Timestamps: is each record only assigned once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp, inner-join

I am working with timestamped records and need to do an inner join based on the timestamp difference. I have been using the `DATEDIFF` function and it seems to be working well. However, the amount of time between timestamps varies. To clarify, sometimes the record appears in table 2 within the same second as table 1, and sometimes the record in table 2 is up to 15 seconds behind the record in table 1. The records in table 1 are always timestamped before table 2. There is no other common field with which I can join, however there is a register number in each table that I am using to increase accuracy by ensuring that the registers are the same.

My question is: if I increase the timestamp difference to do the inner join (e.g. where the `DATEDIFF` = 1 or 2 or 3... or 15) will records only be joined once? Or would my table contain duplicate records from table 1 (e.g. where record 1 is joined to record 4 in table 2 where the diff is 4 seconds, and is also joined with record 7 from table 2 where the diff is 11 seconds)?

The reason my statement works now is that no registers have records with less than 6 seconds in between, so even if there are multiple timestamps that would match, the matching of registers eliminates this problem.

My Statement is currently working as:

```
SELECT *
INTO AtriumSequoiaJoin5
FROM Atrium INNER JOIN Sequoia ON Atrium.Reader = Sequoia.theader_pos_name
WHERE (
    ((DateDiff(s,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime]))=0 
    Or (DateDiff(s,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime]))=1 
    Or (DateDiff(s,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime]))=2 
    Or (DateDiff(s,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime]))=3 
    Or (DateDiff(s,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime]))=4 
    Or (Datediff(s,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime]))=5)
    )
ORDER BY Sequoia.theader_id;
```

Comment: Note: you can use just `DateDiff(s,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime]) between 0 and 5` instead of this long WHERE statement. Even if you use some interval of seconds (0 to 5) it already can join more then 1 rows from `Sequoia` table.

Comment: I am guessing that by timestamp you mean a datetime value? Be careful with your words as timestamp is a datatype in sql server that has nothing to do with the time of day.

Comment: Why are you using all these OR predicates here? Why not simply use a range instead of checking the same value over and over again? Your entire where clause can easily be reduced to a single predicate. Regardless, joining on datediff like this is highly prone to error. You really should have a better method of joining rows then assuming the dates are close. This is what foreign keys were designed to be used for.

Comment: there has to be a single record that is closest in proximity (well there could be zero also), and you can find that SINGLE record, which is then the one most likely to be the record you want - see my answer for my idea

Comment: @SeanLange, I wish there was another field that I could use to join the tables, but unfortunately they are from two different companies and databases. I will also change my statement to between 0-5. I was just wary of double-joining if a record satisfied the requirements for multiple joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could CROSS APPLY to the closest record in proximity.  That's by no means ideal however, what if there are multiple records written at the same time?  You perhaps should give the first table an identity field, then update the next table with scopeidentity

```
SELECT *

INTO AtriumSequoiaJoin5

FROM Atrium CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Sequoia WHERE 
            Atrium.Reader = Sequoia.theader_pos_name 
            ORDER BY Datediff(millisecond,[Atrium].[Date2],[Sequoia].[theader_tdatetime])) DQ

ORDER BY Sequoia.theader_id;
```

Comment: I think this should work because the only records that are written at the same time occur at different registers and are eliminated by matching Atrium.Reader = Sequoia.theader_pos_name.